# Why my on member join code is No Working?

Tags: discord, discord.py

i tried to make auto roles bot but its not working
Help me please im just Beginner ;-;

my code:

```py
@bot.event
async def on_member_join(member): 
    rank = discord.utils.get(member.guild.roles, name="Unverify") 
    await member.add_roles(role)
```

Comment: Is there any error?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You defined "rank" and use "role"?

see this:

```py
@bot.event
async def on_member_join(member): 
    rank = discord.utils.get(member.guild.roles, name="Unverify") # rank
    await member.add_roles(role)  ### role ###
```

be carful.

Comment: i'm sorry i just define wrong variables
thank you for remind me :D